# HTML Canvas scale with left edge fixed

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create an element that will be scaled, but I need it to be affixed to the left edge. I was looking at the documentation here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp

where it states: "The positioning will also be scaled. If you scale(2,2); drawings will be positioned twice as far from the left and top of the canvas as you specify."

Any tips on how to keep it stationary from the top left position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ctx.translate` to move the canvas origin back to the top left corner after scaling.

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(5,5,25,15);
ctx.scale(2,2);
ctx.translate(-2.5, -2.5);
ctx.strokeRect(5,5,25,15);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```